# THREE.JS: How to rotate object around its centre in vertex shader?

Tags: matrix, three.js, rotation, glsl

I have a simple THREE.Points object. Have to rotate it around its Y centre axis via shader (green line), as well as general object position. I have commented it by now, so it doesn't affect the rotation issue.

[image]

Now it has the wrong "orbital" rotation. Pretty sure that I need to play with tPos. Have tried without any success.

```js
       

  var stats, scene, renderer;
  var camera, cameraControl, mesh;

  if( !init() ) animate();

  function init(){

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
     antialias  : true,
     preserveDrawingBuffer : true
    });
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xBBBBBB, 1 );
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   scene = new THREE.Scene();

   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
   camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
   scene.add(camera);

            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

            var vertices = new Float32Array( [
                
                -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

                1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                -1.0, -1.0,  1.0
                
            ] );

            geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
            
            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

            side : THREE.DoubleSide,
                
            uniforms: {

            parentPosition: { value: new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) },
            rotation: { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
            texture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "assets/blob.png" ) }

            },

             vertexShader: document.getElementById( "vertexshader" ).textContent,
             fragmentShader: document.getElementById( "fragmentshader" ).textContent,
             alphaTest: 0.9

            } );
            
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add(mesh);

  }

  function animate() {
            
                     //mesh.material.uniforms.parentPosition.value.x += 0.01;
      mesh.material.uniforms.rotation.value += 0.01;
            
   requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            
   render();

  }


  function render() {
            
   renderer.render( scene, camera );
            
  }
```

```css
body{ margin: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>three.js template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

        
        <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

    uniform vec3 parentPosition;
    uniform float rotation;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying mat4 vPosition;
    
    void main() {
    
        mat4 tPos = mat4(vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
                       vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0),
                       vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0),
                       vec4(0,0,0,1.0));
                        
        mat4 rYPos = mat4(vec4(cos(rotation),0.0,sin(rotation),0.0),
                        vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0),
                        vec4(-sin(rotation),0.0,cos(rotation),0.0),
                        vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));

        vPosition = tPos * rYPos;
        
        vColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        vec3 newPosition = position + parentPosition;
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vPosition * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );
        gl_PointSize = 32.0 * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        
    }
    
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

    uniform sampler2D texture;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    varying mat4 vPosition;
    
    void main() {

        gl_FragColor = vColor;
        gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
    
    }
    
</script>
        
        
 </head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
mat4 tPos = mat4(vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
                       vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0),
                       vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0),
                       vec4(0,0,0,1.0));

mat4 rYPos = mat4(vec4(cos(rotation),0.0,sin(rotation),0.0),
                        vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0),
                        vec4(-sin(rotation),0.0,cos(rotation),0.0),
                        vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));

vPosition = tPos * rYPos;

vColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
vec3 newPosition = position + parentPosition;
vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vPosition * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at the source code of [this example](https://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html) from AlteredQualia.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. The code works fine. Have to set all Z values to 0.0.

```
var vertices = new Float32Array( [

-1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
1.0,  1.0,  0.0,

1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
-1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
-1.0, -1.0,  0.0

] );
```